# Cannot set variable from Airflow cli

Tags: python, airflow

In Airflow, when I run, using the airflow cli,

```
airflow variables -s my_conf '{"my_conf": "false"}'
```

I get

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: variable
[SQL: DELETE FROM variable WHERE variable."key" = ?]
```

why is there no `variable` table? Is this an airflow bug or should I be setting a variable in a different way?

Comment: is `airflow variables -s my_conf ` really a valid command? Shouldn't it be something like [`airflow variables set <key> <value>`](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#set_repeat1)?

Comment: at least that's what I understand from the docs: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/cli-ref#variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try running `airflow initdb`? This will create all the required tables.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
airflow variables -s my_conf false
```

or if you want to use a dictionary, put it in a file and try

```
airflow variables -e my_fict_path
```

Comment: The issue of the first one is the same: `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: variable`